# Can two select use use the same value?

Tags: visualforce, controller

I'm trying to synchronize two selectList together using the following :

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedOption}" size="1" onchange="myFunction()">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionsList}"/>
</apex:selectList>

(other code lies here)

<apex:selectList value="{!selectedOption}" size="1" onchange="myFunction()">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionsList}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

The second selectList is working perfectly fine, but the first one does not send the good information to the controller. I am missing something ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the code is submitted to the server, the latter value overwrites the former. That's just the nature of how Visualforce works. However, you could wrap this up in an `apex:actionRegion` with `apex:actionSupport` to support this use case.

```
<apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="false">
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedOption}" size="1">
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!myPageAction}" reRender="form" />
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionsList}"/>
</apex:selectList>
</apex:actionRegion>

(other code lies here)

<apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="false">
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedOption}" size="1">
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!myPageAction}" rerender="form" />
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!optionsList}"/>
</apex:selectList>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

See [`apex:actionSupport`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) and [`apex:actionRegion`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionRegion.htm) for more information.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot.